Can Someone Help me here? I want to know about size from where it's value set?
I am Using React native with expo router version 50.0.15. Recently, I have implemented the Bottom tab menu.
I want to know from where the icon size value is set?
I want to change the size for each menu in bottom tab.
I am talking about this size:
<MaterialCommunityIcons name={icon} color={color} size={size} />

This is below sample code.
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

function Feed() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Feed!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function Profile() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Profile!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function Notifications() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Notifications!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Feed"
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: 'red',
        inactiveTintColor: 'green',
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home2"
        component={Feed}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Updates',
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            const icon = focused ? 'settings-sharp' : 'alarm-bell';
            return (
              <></>
              //<Icon name={icon} size={size} color={color} type={'Ionicons'} />
            );
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Feed"
        component={Feed}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Notifications"
        component={Notifications}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Updates',
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            const icon = focused ? 'bell' : 'alarm-bell';
            return (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name={icon} color={color} size={size} />
            );
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={Profile}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyTabs />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

So for now I have done giving the static size of each icons.
Once I will know from where the default value is changing then I will change the default value.

Does this answer your question? How to set Icon size in react-native-navigation bottom tab bar

no, that solution, I just used but challenge  here is I have define the size each of icons.
